# Runtime Error R6034, after installing OpenCV on Windows 7 for Python3

Tags: python-3.x, windows, opencv

I recently installed OpenCV.  I started by installing Anaconda 3, and followed instructions on building OpenCV found here: https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-windows/   It installed okay and I get access to the libraries in Python (see output below)

```
Python 3.6.7 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 10 2018, 20:35:02) [MSC v.
1915 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.__version__
'4.0.1-dev'
>>>
```

However, every time I open the anaconda command line interface, a popup comes up saying:

> Runtime Error
>
> Program C:\ ... \python.exe
>
> R6034
>
> An application has made an attempt to load the C runtime library
>   incorrectly. Please contact the application's support team for more
>   information.

I have looked for this error and found that it has to do with MicroSoft build tools conflicts.  For example a library is built for msvcr90.dll, then when you go to use this library, the OS finds 2 versions in the PATH.

For me, this only happens in the Anaconda Prompt, so I looked deep into the Path on that environment using commands like `$where msvc*` etc; however, I can not find any conflicts.

So far it is just annoying, but I would like to resolve it.

Answer (score 1):

You said you installed Anaconda 3; if you have previous versions of Anaconda installed and you installed libraries that required MicroSoft build tools, that can cause a conflict.
To fix this, uninstall previous versions of Anaconda.

Comment: I had MiniConda installed.  After I removed MiniConda from my path, everything worked fine.  Thank you